# ¿Por qué cuando paso el cursor sobre un elemento el estilo se aplica a todos?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una réplica en CSS y HTML de esta página web que se ve en la siguiente imagen. Esta es la página original como se ve cuando pones el cursor sobre el icono, este el fondo se hace amarillo y el icono blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente imagen es mi réplica de CSS y HTML y como pueden ver cuando pongo el cursor sobre el icono. Cambia todos los iconos y no funciona como en la página original.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que quiero que quede igual que la página original. Pido su ayuda para ayudarme a solucionar este problema. Muchas gracias.
aquí está la pagina original https://vivelaconco.com/gdl/ca.html

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


body {
    background-image: url(image/speakersbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

#nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px;
    background: url("image/banner-inner2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;

    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#logotipo-1 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#logotipo-1 img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 52px;
}

#logotipo-1 h3 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(50, 51, 51, .8);
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}


#menu-lista {
    max-width: 440px;
    float: right;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 255px;
    padding-top: 46px;
}

#lista-2 {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#lista-2 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;

    font-size: 13px;

    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;

    padding: 28px 20px;
}

.menu-vertical {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    width: 190px;
    height: 130px;

    background: rgba(85, 75, 185, .98);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 16px 8px;

}

#lista-2 li:hover .menu-vertical {
    display: block;

}

.menu-vertical {
    background-color: #534cb9;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-vertical li {
    height: 35px;
}

.menu-vertical .fila-vertical {
    height: 35px;
    width: 190px;

}

.menu-vertical li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .6;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    padding: 10px !important;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.menu-vertical li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#comprar-tickets {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: -660px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;
}

#comprar-tickets h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 51px;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
}



#contenedor {
    /* display: inline-flex;*/

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    /*
    width: 972px;*/
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cuadros {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 262px;

    margin-top: 68px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-right: 30px;


}

.image img {
    width: 267px;
    height: 288px;
    background: none;
    border: solid 14px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

}



#segundo-contenedor {
    /* display: inline-flex;*/

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    /*
    width: 972px;*/
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

}

.cuadros-contenido {
    display: block;
    width: 242px;
    height: 263px;
    margin-top: 94px;
    margin-left: 57px;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-right: 1px;

    margin-bottom: -27px;

}

.cuadros-contenido #redes {
    position: absolute;
    background: #654fb1;
    width: 295px;
    height: 97px;
    margin: -26px -27px;
    opacity: .8;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.cuadros-contenido:hover #redes {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

#redes img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

#redes .face {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 25px;

}

#redes .insta {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 47px;
    margin-left: 25px;

}

.cuadros-contenido .texto {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1b273d;
    width: 295px;
    height: 219px;
    margin: 71px -27px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.cuadros-contenido:hover .texto {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.cuadros-contenido .texto p {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -9px 10px;
}

.cuadros-contenido .texto h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 3.9000000000000004rem;
    font-weight: 700;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#pie-pagina {

    background-image: url(image/footer-bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background: rgba(27, 39, 61, .95);
    opacity: .8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#pie-pagina .imagen-1 {
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 170px;
}

#menu-iconos {
    max-width: 440px;
    float: right;
    background: transparent;
    /*
    padding-right: 255px;
    padding-top: 46px;
*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


#lista-iconos {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#lista-iconos li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    background: #bcbec5;
    border-radius: 999px;
}

#lista-iconos li img {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 13px 12px;
    
}

#lista-iconos:hover li {
    background: #efa506;
    transition: all 200ms;
   
}

#lista-iconos:hover img {

    transition: all 200ms;
    background: white;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3.01 ejercicio desde 0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <div class="barra">

            <div id="logotipo-1">
                <span class="logo-1">
                    <img src="image/con-co.png" alt="concomics">
                </span>
                <h3>vive la conco</h3>
            </div>

            <nav id="menu-lista"> <!-- ESTO MUEVE EL MENU DE IZQ. A DER. -->

                <ul id="lista-2">
                    <li><a href="#">INVITADOS. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">CONCURSOS. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ALLEY'S. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">GAMING. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">INFO GENERAL. </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="comprar-tickets">
                <div id="comprar">
                    <h3>CONTENIDO</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor">

        <div class="cuadros">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/amatesaurius.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/michdahaka.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/rizel.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/darkittie.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div n class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/pikacos.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/dalia-cos.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/pretty.png" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/pinku.jpg" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cuadros">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/puchys-love.jpg" alt="concomics">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="segundo-contenedor">

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Amatesaurius </h2>
                <p>
                    Soy Amatesaurius, recibida de Ingeniería Biomédica, tengo 8 años haciendo
                    cosplay, así como siendo streamer desde hace 6 años. Me gusta mucho hacer personajes
                    tanto de videojuegos como de anime. He sido presentadora y conductora de varios eventos
                </p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Michdahaka </h2>
                <p>
                    Cosplayer y streamer. Soy amante de los videojuegos, principalmente RPG y
                    de terror, el anime, la literatura de terror, ciencia ficción y hacer
                    ejercicio. Me gusta representar personajes fuertes y busco inspirar a
                    los demás a siempre esforzarse por lo que desean
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Rizel Cosplay </h2>
                <p>
                    Cosplayer con una extensa trayectoria y 16 años de experiencia he sido Ganadora
                    de innumerables Concursos de Cosplay por toda la República y el más Importantes
                    actualmente Representante Mexicana y Ganadora del 2do Lugar a nivel mundial
                    en el World Cosplay Summit 2022
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Darkittie Aensland </h2>
                <p>
                    Soy una cosplayer creativa y polifacética, que ama a los gatos, en mis tiempos
                    libres me dedico a ser cosplayer, cosmaker, propmaker, streamer e integrante del
                    canal de YouTube Geeky World. 7 años de trayectoria, con alrededor de 70
                    cosplays realizados totalmente por mi
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Pikacos </h2>
                <p>
                    Por el día soy Diseñadora/Ilustradora y por las noches Creadora contenido & Cosplayer
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> DaliaSCos </h2>
                <p>
                    Cosplayer y cosmaker originaria de Matamoros, Tamaulipas. Llevo más de 10 años en
                    el ambito del cosplay nacional, recientemente fui parte del primer equipo representante
                    de México en GICOF 2022 celebrada en la ciudad de Bucheon en Corea del Sur,
                    obteniendo el tercer lugar en dicha competencia internacional
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Pretty Pics with LOVS </h2>
                <p>
                    Mi nombre es Sofi. De día, soy una animadora godín. De noche, soy cosplayer y
                    streamer!. Me encanta conectar con gente a través de mis cosplay. He conocido
                    cosplayers, fotógrafos, y gente maravillosa gracias a esto, ¡y nada me hace
                    más feliz que formar parte de una conve y poder conocer más gente!
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Pinku Cosplay </h2>
                <p>

                    Con más de diez años de trayectoria, Pinkues diseñadora gráfica de profesión, amante de la
                    fotografía, el teatro .

                    Ganadora de la CCP, ganadora femenil del concurso nacional de cosplay IMAGINA 2018 y representante
                    de México en YCC Brasil, ha participado en concursos de cosplay en varios estados de Mexico.

                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cuadros-contenido">

            <div id="redes">

                <img class="face" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                <img class="insta" src="../3.01-ejercicio/image/instagram.png" alt="instagram">

            </div>

            <div class="texto">

                <h2> Puchys Love</h2>
                <p>
                ha recorrido casi todo México y algunos
                    otros países 

                    Ha colaborado con varias empresas de videojuegos como Activision, Riot, Tencent, entre otras;
                    también entrevistada por varios medios de comunicación como revistas, periódicos, sitios web,
                    streamings y programas de televisión; 
            </div>

        </div>

        <footer id="pie-pagina">
            <div class="imagen-1">
                    <img src="image/footer-logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
    
                <nav id="menu-iconos">
                    <ul id="lista-iconos">
                        
                            <li> <img src="image/facebook-banner.svg" alt="facebook"></li>
                            <li>  <img src="image/instagram-2.png" alt="facebook"> </li>
                            <li> <img src="image/twitter.png" alt="facebook"> </li>
                            <li> <img src="image/e-mail.png" alt="facebook"> </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>
 
            <div class="aviso">
                <h3>Aviso de Privacidad y Políticas del Evento</h3>
            </div>
        </footer>
       
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muy probablemente el sitio original usa íconos de _font-awesome_ o similares. No son imágenes como tal. Por cierto, es hover* :)

Comment: 1.- Debes colocar un [MRE] con énfasis en lo mínimo. El código que has publicado es TODA la página cuando tu problema está solo en una pequeña porción de esta. 2.- Tu estas usando imágenes para los iconos `<img>` y la original usa fuentes (`font`) con lo cual es muchísimo más fácil realizar aquel efecto.

Comment: muchas gracias pòr tu respuesta.

Comment: En la línea "#lista-iconos:hover li {" estas cogiendo todos los elementos li en el "#lista-iconos:hover", para especificar que solo cambie el li en el que tienes el cursor cámbialo a   "#lista-iconos li:hover  {"

Comment: Antonio Torres muchas gracias por tu respuesta si funciono.gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: padaleiana muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides responder a tu pregunta con lo que te ha sido útil (o pídele a @AntonioTorres que la responda). Luego, no olvides [aceptar](/help-accepted-answer) la respuesta.

Comment: @AntonioTorres muchas gracias como le hago para darle una buena calificacion a tu respuesta?? muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo has solucionado pero te detallo un poco el funcionamiento del :hover que tienes.

```
#lista-iconos:hover li {
    background: #efa506;
    transition: all 200ms;
   
}
```

Tienes un contenedor ("#lista-iconos") con varios elementos (li).

Al poner :hover en el contenedor se activara en cuanto el cursor entre el los márgenes del contenedor modificándote todos los elementos ya que el contenedor es el mismo par todos.

---

```
#lista-iconos li:hover {
    background: #efa506;
    transition: all 200ms;
   
}
```

En este caso el :hover se activara cuando el cursor entre en los márgenes de cualquier elemento y el elemento que se active es el que se modifica.

Puedes buscar mas información aquí:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.php